# Array.map() runs twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an Array of length 8

```
const [macs,setMacs]=useState([{"mac_empfangen":"f2:c5:5b:1c:d8:59"},{"mac_empfangen":"c4:9f:1a:15:30:65"},...])
```

Now I want to map over this array with

```
const nameMacs=(
   macs.map(mac=>(
      <AddDevice mac_empfangen={mac.mac_empfangen}/>
   )
)
```

But when I log the result in the console,

```
const nameMacs=(
   macs.map(mac=>(
      console.log(mac)
      <AddDevice mac_empfangen={mac.mac_empfangen}/>
   )
)
```

Then I see, that the function maps over the array twice.

Any ideas, how to solve it?

Comment: Is that because your component mounts twice?

Comment: Read about useMemo and useCallback hooks in React

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nameMacs = useMemo(() => {
    <>
    {macs.map((mac, i) =>
    <AddDevice key={i} mac_empfangen={mac.mac_empfangen} />
    )}
    </>
}, [macs])
```

This way, nameMacs will only reload if macs changes. Also, don't forget the key.